# AppAssertionCredentials fail with 401

Tags: python, google-api, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

Following the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=en_US

I try running this python script on my google compute engine instance:

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.gce import AppAssertionCredentials

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore")
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build('datastore', 'v1beta2', http=http)
x = service.datasets().lookup(body='', datasetId='surferjeff-easybates').execute(http=http)
```

But I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/surferjeff-easybates/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    x = service.datasets().lookup(body='', datasetId='surferjeff-easybates').execute(http=http)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 723, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/surferjeff-easybates/lookup?alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials">
```

And I have verified that my account has datastore enabled.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to a Google simple bug.

When you create a new instance using the cloud console and check the *"Allow API access to all Google Cloud services in the same project"*, you are including this instance in all of the possible cloud scopes.

When you try to view which REST request generated this great functionality (by pressing the *"Equivalent REST or command line"* button) you see that the instance is generated using one global scope as follows:

```
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
  ]
```

If you attempt to create this instance using the Google API client (apiclient) with the same scopes you find out that it cannot get valid credentials to use the Datastore service.

The solution resides in the fact that the single scope is apparently not what Google assigns to your instance when you create it through the console.

If you open the instance details after creating it, you find out that it has the following scopes:

```
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
```

Once you mention datastore's scope explicitly, things will work as expected.